# Do web extension's content script run on the main thread of a web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, tensorflow.js

My webpage has image recognition algorithm running (tensorflow js). Apart from this, it also does lot of frontend heavy task...This was running fine until I added the ML algorithm. Since the tensorflow algorithm made my webpage slow and unresponsive, i had to take them out. I wanted to know if I put them in a web extension, will it still run on the main thread or will it be on a different thread. My web application requires DOM access and web extension has that...(any suggestions to run ml image recognition algorithm on a web page without disturbing the web page will also be helpful)

Comment: There are no threads in JavaScript, there are only workers but those are different beasts. The content scripts run in the one and only environment of the web page. Depending on what exactly you do you can probably create an iframe pointing to an html file from your extension exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and do the processing inside or even create workers inside that iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to move one of the tasks onto web worker so it does not block the main thread on the webpage for rendering etc. See this lovely writeup:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/offscreen-canvas

I have manged to use TFJS models with OffscreenCanvas in Chrome extension for example and it worked fine for me. Worth a try.